# How to define dynamically background color in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

In Lightning is not possible to access CSS Style and modify css properties like background color. In my case I need to change CSS Background color style based on custom record field value.

I am interested in how to implement this on Lightning.

Comment: What do you mean in Lightning? Are you developing Lightning components?

Comment: Yes, I mean how to achieve in Lightning components the same effect if we use javascript with jquery function something like $(elem).css('background', dynamicalValueOfCssBackgroundDerivenFromSObjectFieldValueOrFromSomewhereElse)

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use inline css - somethink like this:

```
<aura:attribute type="String" name="colorBackground" default='blue'/> 
<div style="{! 'background-color:' + v.colorBackground }">
     <!-- code -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Lightning components, you can also use html properties and Javascript code.

First, you can define an id to your custom div using:

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

Then, you'll be able to modify its background using Javascript:

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById("test");
myDiv.style.background = "dynamicalValueOfCssBackgroundDerivenFromSObjectFieldValueOrF‌​romSomewhereElse";
```